# google maps api add a LatLng to the start of a polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps api to draw a gps track on a map. For this i am using a polyline overlay. So far, this works fine, but i would like to dynamically add and remove points from both sides of the polyline.

For removing points and adding points to the end of a polyline i know that i can use

```
google.maps.Polyline.getPath().removeAt(index);
```

and

```
google.maps.Polyline.getPath().push(LatLng);
```

Is there a function to add points to the start of a polyline easily? (similar to how one would use `array.unshift(value)` for adding an element to the start of an array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path of a polyline is a MVCArray class which has array methods. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MVCArray

Therefore you could use insertAt() insert a new point at index 0.

```
insertAt(0, item)
```